# least value of floor of $z_{1}+z_{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},z_{4}$ are the roots of the equation
>
> $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0.$ Then the least value of
>
> $\lfloor |z_{1}+z_{2}|\rfloor +1$ is

Try: From given equation $z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=0$

$$\frac{z^5-1}{z-1}=0(z-1\neq 0\Rightarrow z\neq 1.)$$

So $$z^5=1\Rightarrow z = (1)^{\frac{1}{5}}=\bigg(\cos 2k\pi+i\sin 2k\pi\bigg)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

So $$z=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{5}} = \cos \frac{2k\pi}{5}+i\sin \frac{2k\pi}{5}.$$

For $k=0,1,2,3,4$

So $$z_{i}\in \cos \frac{2k\pi}{5}+i\sin \frac{2k\pi}{5}$$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5.$

Now i did not understand how i find least of $z_{1}+z_{2}.$

could some help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Note that minimum value of $|z_1+z_2|$ is the minimum magnitude of the vector that can be obtained by the sum of vectors with angle $2\pi /5$ and $4\pi/5$ between them, all having magnitude of $1$ (by geometrical interpretation of $n^{th}$ roots of $1$).

$$|z_1+z_2|=\sqrt{1+1+2\cos\theta}$$
$\cos\theta=0.309$ OR $-0.809$ (corresponding to $72$ and $144$ degrees respectively).
So, $$\text{min}|z_1+z_2|=\sqrt{0.381}\implies \text{ans}=0+1=\boxed{1}.$$

Comment: Your claim about the sum of vectors having minimum magnitude while correct only depends on *visual inspection*. A **rigorous argument** would be more appropriate for that.

Comment: @AnuragA I completely disagree. Note that the person asking the question has already written the general form of solutions, it means he has a good understanding of complex numbers. That formula (for z) combined with De Moivre's Rule itself tells you that the roots will be the vertices of $n$ sided regular polygon ($n=5$ in this case), inscribed in a circle with center at origin. Further, the almost every problem related to addition in complex numbers becomes way easier if you treat it as a vector addition. I don't think I need to give any rigurous argument in the favor of my answer

Comment: I am well aware of all the different mathematical stuff you have used but how do you know that those angles are the ones which give you the minimum? Isn't it based on visual inspection.

Comment: @AnuragA There are just 2 possible angles. $2\pi/5$ and $4\pi/5$. I hope you know this, because of the angles of a regular pentagon (without visual inspection). I've given both of the possible values. I don't know what you're thinking is wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}}$, then each root of the given equation $z^4+\dotsb+1=0$ is a power of $\alpha$. Let $z_1=\alpha^k$ and $z_2=\alpha^j$, where $k \leq j$ and $k,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Let us first consider $$|z_1+z_2|=|\alpha^k||1+\alpha^{j-k}|=|1+\alpha^{j-k}|=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(j-k)}{5}\right)}=2\left|\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(j-k)}{10}\right)\right|$$

Thus we want to minimize $\color{blue}{\left\lfloor 2\left|\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(j-k)}{10}\right)\right|\right\rfloor +1}$.

Observe that the only possible values of $\left\lfloor 2\left|\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(j-k)}{10}\right)\right|\right\rfloor$ are $0,1,2$ ($\because 0 \leq |\cos \theta| \leq 1$).

We can show that this could be zero. Because $j-k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, therefore $j-k$ can take the value $2$. In which case,
(using the decreasing nature of the cosine function) we have $$\frac{4\pi}{10} > \frac{\pi}{3} \implies \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{10}\right) < \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Thus  $\left\lfloor 2\left|\cos\left(\frac{2\pi(j-k)}{10}\right)\right|\right\rfloor$ can take the value $0$. Thus the minimum value of the given expression is $\color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\frac{z^5-1}{z-1}=0(z-1\neq 0\Rightarrow z\neq 1.)$$
>
> So $$z^5=1\Rightarrow z = (1)^{\frac{1}{5}}=\bigg(\cos 2k\pi+i\sin 2k\pi\bigg)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$
>
> So $$z=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{5}} = \cos \frac{2k\pi}{5}+i\sin \frac{2k\pi}{5}.$$
>
> For $k=0,1,2,3,4$

Not quite. Don't forget that $z \neq 1$, so $k \neq 0$.

---

$|z_1| = |z_2| = 1$ because they're roots of unity. Therefore $|z_1 + z_2| \le 2$ with equality only when $z_1 = z_2$. Also $0 \le |z_1 + z_2|$ with equality only when $z_1 = -z_2$.

Thus immediately we see that $\lfloor |z_{1}+z_{2}|\rfloor$ is $0$ or $1$.

To see geometrically whether it must be $1$, consider the Argand diagram. If you draw a circle of unit radius centred on the origin, and then a second circle of unit radius centred on $z_1$ (on the circumference of the first circle), by the standard compass-and-ruler construction of a hexagon a third of the circumference of the second circle lies inside the first circle. Therefore the question is whether any of the other roots lie in that third when we translate the second circle back to the first circle, and the answer is obviously yes, since they're spaced every fifth of the circumference.

[image: Diagram of the circles etc]

---

Alternatively, taking a more algebraic approach: since the coefficients are real, roots occur in conjugate pairs. It suffices to find a root whose real part is in the range $(-\tfrac12, \tfrac12)$.